# how to create connection strings by reflection (edmx, entity framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, edmx

the problem is as follows; We have code that talks to many databases that all have the same or similar model.

The way that the code is structured is that each business project just has a data context defined of the tables it cares about (there are over a thousand). This means that we end up having a need to generate connection strings based on server information.

The problem becomes the metadata=res://*/DataModel.XXXX.csdl|res://*/DataModel.XXXX.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.XXXX.msl section; as this name is not standardized.

Is there a way to use the System.Data.Objects.ObjectContex combined with reflection to solve for XXXX.

the code we use that requires us to solve for that is as follows.

```
var scsb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
scsb.DataSource = (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DatabaseServerUri) ? Uri : DatabaseServerUri) + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SqlInstanceName) ? string.Empty : string.Format(@"\\{0}", SqlInstanceName));
scsb.InitialCatalog = MainDatabase; 
scsb.IntegratedSecurity = false;
scsb.Password = "stuff";
scsb.UserID = "morestuff";
scsb.ConnectTimeout = 3600;

var builder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.Metadata = "res://*/DataModel.XXXX.csdl|res://*/DataModel.XXXX.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.XXXX.msl"; 
builder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient"; 
builder.ProviderConnectionString = scsb.ConnectionString;

return builder.ConnectionString;
```

Comment: your question is not very clear. could you try explaining it better?

Comment: I'm trying to build connection strings to be used in entity framework using reflection. But that requires I solve for the csdl, ssdl, and msl names and I can't figure out how to get those values trough reflection.

Comment: @BasHamer What server information will you use to create the connection strings (when you say based on server information). If model is same for different database, all you have to do is change "provider connection string". Please provide as much more information as possible.

Comment: I have the server info from a 3rd source and the ObjectContext type. So the goal would be to use reflection on the ObjectContext to solve for the missing bits.

Comment: You could just set it to Metadata=res://*/ to load all metadata files in an assembly (see [Connection Strings - Model and Mapping File Locations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending my comment to an answer

Model and Mapping files are normally embedded in the assembly (where your ObjectContext is) so you can provide that assembly name to read them from assembly's embedded resources. To achieve this you could do the following:

```
builder.Metadata = string.Format("res://{0}", typeof(MyObjectContext).Assembly.FullName);
```